# Let L be all linear transformations. Let S be subset of L invertible linear transformations. Prove S is open in L.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $L (\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the set of all linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n$ subset of natural number. Let $S$ be the subset of $L (\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ containing all invertible linear transformations. Prove that $S$ is open in $L (\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I have no clue at all how to approach this problem... Please help me...

Comment: How is an open set defined?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $det: L(R^n,R^n)\rightarrow R$ which sends a matrix $A$ to its determinant $det(A)$, $det$ is continuous and $S$ is the preimage of the open subset $R-\{0\}$ thus is open.